# caliburn.micro - Error on window close: Collection was modified enumeration operation may not execute

Tags: c#, caliburn.micro

We're currently writing a WPF application in the Caliburn Micro framework. Sometimes when the app shuts down, we get the following exception:

```
Collection was modified, Enumeration operation may not execute.
```

With stack trace:

```
at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowInvalidOperationException(ExceptionResource resource)
at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.Enumerator.MoveNextRare()
at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.Enumerator.MoveNext()
at System.Linq.Enumerable.<OfTypeIterator>d__aa`1.MoveNext()
at Caliburn.Micro.EnumerableExtensions.Apply[T](IEnumerable`1 enumerable, Action`1 action)
at Caliburn.Micro.Conductor`1.Collection.AllActive.OnDeactivate(Boolean close)
at Caliburn.Micro.Screen.Caliburn.Micro.IDeactivate.Deactivate(Boolean close)
at Caliburn.Micro.WindowManager.WindowConductor.Closed(Object sender, EventArgs e)
at System.Windows.Window.OnClosed(EventArgs e)
at System.Windows.Window.WmDestroy()
at System.Windows.Window.WindowFilterMessage(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
at System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.PublicHooksFilterMessage(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)
at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
```

It seems that the Conductor's Collection.AllActive.items enumerable is being modified during enumeration as the function attempts to deactivate all the items. Internet searches suggest running a .ToList() before enumeration where this can occur, but obviously this code is in the framework, and outside of our direct control.

We're probably doing something which is making the error more likely, but we're not sure if this is the desired behaviour in Caliburn either. Could there be something we're doing wrong with the way we shut things down?

Thank you in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case anyone else has a similar issue...

It was to do with our model extending `Conductor<Screen>.Collection.AllActive`.

We had our `Items` list contain Screens, which when they got deactivated (ie each Screen closed), it would be removed from `Items`.

(EDIT: I know that when items are closed, they are automatically removed from Items by Caliburn anyway, but we wanted to potentially add a new item in this scenario, and adding a new item during OnCollectionChanged caused errors. These could be fixed by adding a delegate / timer, which then made testing more difficult. In the end, it was discussed and we decided this would be an easier solution).

Ie, we had:

```
SOMEWHERE WE ADDED ITEMS:
    var screen = new Screen();
    screen.Deactivated += OnScreenDeactivated;
    Items.Add(screen);
    screen.Activate()

AND:
    private void OnScreenDeactivated(object sender, DeactivationEventArgs e)
    {
        Items.Remove(sender as Screen);
    }
```

But of course, when the Conductor closes, Caliburn Micro iterates over all the Items, and deactivates them in turn. If we had >2 items in the `Items` list then this would cause the above error.

The fix was simply to change the function to:

```
    private void OnScreenDeactivated(object sender, DeactivationEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsActive)
        {
            return;
        }
        Items.Remove(sender as Screen);
    }
```

So that if the conductor was closing, it would not remove Items from the list. (This might not work in all situations, but worked for us!)